# Find the Wronskian of the solutions of Legendre Differential Equation .

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Given the differential equation is $$(2x+5)^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-(2x+5)\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=0$$ on $[-1,2]$ Where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are its two solutions find the $W(y_1,y_2)$

**solution i tried**-Here I have considered  given differential equation is a Legendre's linear differential equation and i am considering $(2x+5)=e^t$

to find complementary solution i proceed as

$$4D(D-1)-2D+2=0$$
$$4D^2-6D+2=0$$

$$2D^2-3D+1=0$$

by middle term splitting  i get two roots
$D=1,D=\frac{1}{2}$

the solution i get is $$y=c_1e^t+c_2e^{\frac{1}{2}}t$$

$$y=c_1(2x+5)+c_2(2x+5)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

here $y_1=(2x+5)$ and $y_2=(2x+5)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

but when i calculate the Wronskian it gives $(2x+5)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ ,but the answer given is $0$ ,i am not getting where  i made mistake

Please help

Thankyou

Comment: There is no way the Wronskian can be zero - there is a theorem which states that if $f,g$ are solutions to a linear differential equation, then $W(f,g) = 0$ implies that the functions are linearly dependent (which is not true in general for $W(f,g) = 0$)

Comment: but here solutions are not L.D?

Comment: That's exactly right - they are linearly independent. The reason we stop with two solutions for second order linear differential equations is because we are told that we expect two linearly independent solutions.